# Select from multiple tables with no duplicate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have complex select statement from 5 tables, 
I want to avoid duplicates rows that have same field value from one of the tables.

```
SELECT  role_enname
          ,lu_app_operations.operation_enname
          , lu_applications.app_enname
          , lu_app_oper_groups.oper_group_enname 
FROM app_operation_roles
      ,roles
      ,lu_app_operations
       ,lu_applications
        ,lu_app_oper_groups
WHERE app_operation_roles.role_id=roles.role_id
AND app_operation_roles.app_operation_id=lu_app_operations.app_operation_id
AND roles.app_id=lu_applications.app_id
AND lu_app_operations.app_oper_group_id=lu_app_oper_groups.app_oper_group_id
AND app_operation_roles.retired  =0
AND roles.retired                =0
```

In this query I don't to show duplicates rows based on `lu_app_operations.operation_enname`

Answer (score 0):

Use the DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT role_enname, <rest of your query>
```

Answer (score 0):

use distinct keyword as follows

```
SELECT  DISTINCT role_enname,lu_app_operations.operation_enname, lu_applications.app_enname,
lu_app_oper_groups.oper_group_enname 
FROM app_operation_roles,roles,lu_app_operations,lu_applications,lu_app_oper_groups
WHERE app_operation_roles.role_id=roles.role_id
AND app_operation_roles.app_operation_id=lu_app_operations.app_operation_id
AND roles.app_id=lu_applications.app_id
AND lu_app_operations.app_oper_group_id=lu_app_oper_groups.app_oper_group_id
AND app_operation_roles.retired  =0 AND roles.retired                =0
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can use Distinct and Group by to get the result, but bear in mind, to join multiple table, the best is still use JOIN instead of AND

```
SELECT  DISTINCT role_enname
      ,lu_app_operations.operation_enname
      , lu_applications.app_enname
      , lu_app_oper_groups.oper_group_enname 
FROM app_operation_roles
,roles
,lu_app_operations
,lu_applications
,lu_app_oper_groups
WHERE app_operation_roles.role_id=roles.role_id
AND app_operation_roles.app_operation_id=lu_app_operations.app_operation_id
AND roles.app_id=lu_applications.app_id
AND lu_app_operations.app_oper_group_id=lu_app_oper_groups.app_oper_group_id
AND app_operation_roles.retired  =0
AND roles.retired                =0 
GROUP BY role_enname, 
lu_app_operations.operation_enname,
lu_applications.app_enname,
lu_app_oper_groups.oper_group_enname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct role_enname,lu_app_operations.operation_enname, lu_applications.app_enname,lu_app_oper_groups.oper_group_enname 
FROM app_operation_roles,roles,lu_app_operations,lu_applications,lu_app_oper_groups
WHERE app_operation_roles.role_id=roles.role_id
AND app_operation_roles.app_operation_id=lu_app_operations.app_operation_id
AND roles.app_id=lu_applications.app_id
AND lu_app_operations.app_oper_group_id=lu_app_oper_groups.app_oper_group_id
AND app_operation_roles.retired =0
AND roles.retired =0
```